# converting python 'repeat' code to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to convert the following python code to Matlab, However, I cannot find the equivalent of repeat. I tried "repmat" but didn't get the same results.
k.size is 64 and LL is a 10 * 10 matrix.

Id = (2 * LL).repeat(K.size).reshape(-1, 8, 8)

Also, How can I convert the (2 * LL).repeat(K.size) to the shape of (-1,8,8) in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following.

```
k_size = 64;                % specify K.size
m = 8; n = 8;               % specify dimensions of each Id slice
LL = reshape(1:100,[],10);  % specify matrix LL

M = 2*LL.';                 %
Id = reshape(repmat(M(:),k_size,1),[],m,n);
```

If you want an equivalent to repeat, you can do the following.

```
function v = repeat(M,k)

Mt = M.';
A = repmat(Mt(:),k).';
v = A(:);

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.